# Error: Found object is not a stat? RStudio Error Message

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, data-representation

I'm learning R (RStudio) and tidyverse to do some statistical analysis and data representation. I'm working with a Melanoma data set. I was asked to approximately find the number of male patients diagnosed with a Malignant tumor and the number of female patients diagnosed with a Benign tumor. Initially, I did this:

```
library(tidyverse)
load("Skin.Rda") #given data file
ggplot(Mela, aes(Behavior, fill=Gender)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

[Gender vs Tumor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Gny.jpg)

But I wasn't satisfied since you can't clearly see the values. I know I can do facets but even then I don't know how to independently set the y-value range for each one.

So, I decided to break it up; Benign vs Malignant. (I also wanted to add text to the top of the bars but I haven't even been able to do the simple part). I narrowed down my data and plotted again:

```
Mela_Benign <- Mela %>% filter(Behavior=="Benign") %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarise(Value=n())
ggplot(Mela_Benign, aes(x=Gender, y=Value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identify")
```

This gave me a very simple table (2x2 male=#, female=#) but it produced a weird error I haven't encountered before:

```
Error: Found object is not a stat.
```

I thought it was because of factor issues, but I used "as.factor()" and still the same. I've searched around but couldn't seem to find an explanation to this error. Maybe it's something simple but I cannot figure it out.

If anyone has any input on the matter I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

"identify" isn't a valid stat. I'm guessing you want to use

```
ggplot(Mela_Benign, aes(x=Gender, y=Value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Are you kidding me?! Wow... am I really that blind!? Thanks for the help and not poking fun at me for this simple mistake.

Comment: Wow, this was so helpful!  I just spent about 15 minutes trying to find out why `geom_point(stat="identitiy")`  was not working.  It was a typo all along

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot you can try this.

```
library(purrr)

Mela%>%
split(.$Behavior)%>%
  map(~ggplot(., aes(x=Gender, fill=Gender))+geom_bar()+
    ggtitle(as.character(.$Behavior))+
     theme_bw()
  )
```